# How do I copy over settings from persistent usb to installation on harddrive?

Tags: settings, persistence

so i just installed Ubuntu 11.10 to my main hard drive. i have a couple of questions.

the main question being, how do i copy over all the programs and settings from the persistent usb that i got settled in with, to the new hard drive install?

second question/scenario: i had a 160gig as my main. power flickered on and off really rapidly the other day. pc is fine, slaved 40 gig was fine, but now the 160gig sounds like it has sand in when i shake it. pc wont recognize it at all. so i've made the 40 gig my main for now. i have another 20 gig, but cant get them to both be recognized by the comp. tried putting them on two different IDE cables. i'm a little confused on what i should have the jumpers set to. i tried setting the 40 gig's jumper to Master, and the 20 gig to Slave, but the pc doesn't like it. basically what i'm asking for is some advice on the jumper settings. both of these are small, old drives. that 20 gigs more is a blessing on this old piece of junk. could really use some advice please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your installed applications with

On your persistent install.

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections > packages.list
```

Transfer `packages.list` to your new install, and run

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections < packages.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Settings varies. User settings are in your home directory, so simply back up home. System settings would be any system file you manually edited.

Of course there are other backup solutions

Here is a link for additional options

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

You will get various opinions regarding which option to use.

Personally I use rsync, but I am not sure if you are interested in a command line tools

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

grsync is covered in that link and is a graphical front end.

You could simply rsync from your persistent system to your hard drive.

As far as your hard drive, aye jumpers are difficult sometimes. Your best bet is to google search the hard drive and see if you can confirm the jumper settings.

If all else fails, try cable select.

Comment: what all g/rsync back up? i'm gonna need to be booted into my persistent from what i gather from your advice. using rsync (i'm cool with command line stuff), will i still need to manually copy my home drive over as well as do the packages listing?

Comment: rsync is a nice little application. It works very much like `cp` ; rsync source destination. To back up home, mount your new home and run `rsync -azvv /home/your_user_name /media/your_new_home` See also http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/ and of course man rsync

Comment: you are most welcome, good luck with your jumpers